# I am attempting to plot a Mandelbrot fractal in python, but I'm not getting the desired output

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, mandelbrot

I am new to coding and I'm trying to create a basic Mandelbrot, but my output is a straight line. When I check the length of the two lists I generated to plot, my function only places 9 elements outside of the Mandelbrot set. Can someone take a look at my code and explain what I'm doing wrong? I think it has something to do with me not understanding numpy arrays very well.

Thanks!

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# We need to create an array containing all of the imaginary numbers contained within out grid.
x = np.linspace(-10,10,10000)

y = np.linspace(-10,10,10000)

x1, y1 = np.meshgrid(x, y) # Mesh both arrays together to get one of each point

c_array = x1 + (y1 * 1.0j)

# Empty lists that will hold our answers
black_list = []

red_list = []

# calculating using f_c (z) = z^2 + c
def perform_calculations(array, n):

    z = 0+0j

    for x_index in range(10000): # looping through every index in the array

        for y_index in range(10000):

            for iteration in range(n): # how many times the calculation will be performed

                c = c_array.item(x_index, y_index) # store every element in the array into c

                z = (z**2) + c # perform the calculation

            if abs(z) > 2:

                black_list.append(c) # place into the black list if it isn't a part of the set

            else:
                red_list.append(c) # place into the red list if it is a part of the set

        return black_list, red_list

# call the function
perform_calculations(c_array, 51)

# separating the real and imaginary elements of the lists
black_real = [element.real for element in black_list] # place the real elements of the black list into a list

black_imaginary = [element.imag for element in black_list] # place the imaginary elements of the black list into a list

red_real = [element.real for element in red_list] # place the real elements of the red list into a list

red_imaginary = [element.imag for element in red_list] # place the imaginary elements of the red list into a list

# create the coordinate plane
plt.figure(figsize = (6, 6))

plt.title('Practice Mandelbrot Set Image')

plt.xlim(-20, 20)

plt.ylim(-20, 20)

plt.xlabel('Real Components')

plt.ylabel('Imaginary Components')


# plot the list values in their respective colors
plt.scatter(black_real, black_imaginary, color = "k")

plt.scatter(red_real, red_imaginary, color = "red")

# show image
plt.show()
```

Comment: You are seeing a straight line because the return statement has the wrong indent. The function returns after the first value of `x_index` is considered.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the indentation to be out of the for loop so that the lists are returned after they've all been completed. Now, however, I'm getting an error: "Terminated due to signal: KILLED (9)".

Comment: The error suggests that evaluation was aborted. The code will probably take a very long time for 10k by 10k image. Have you looked at numpy implementations of the mandelbrot set?

Comment: I haven't. I'm very new to this. To be completely honest, I don't know what that means. So, because you said that 10kx10k was the problem for the error, I made it 100x100. It ran, but the image printed is a square.

Comment: There are a few other issues. First, you need to move the definitions of `z` and `c` to be just after the second for loop (`y_index`). Second, you need to set `z = c` before the iterations start. Also, try replacing `abs(z) > 2` with `abs(z) > 2 or np.isnan(z)`, as `z`'s will overflow for some initial values.

Comment: For reference, here is a nice numpy [implementation](https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/auto_examples/plot_mandelbrot.html).

Comment: Thank you. I made the changes and I'm getting my black background with a red circle. So, I'm making progress. Thank you for the reference!!! This code is so efficient. Mine takes a much longer time to run.